# Good partition setup for Arch/WIndows 8.1 dualboot?

Tags: linux, partitioning, arch-linux, lenovo-laptop

This is going to be my first try of Arch. I have used various distro's before, mainly debian based. Since I've recently gotten a new laptop, I wanted to try dualbooting arch with the already installed windows 8.1.
My setup is as follows:

```
  Lenovo Y500 laptop with 2 harddisks
    16GB SSD, used by ExpressCache, how can I disable this?
    1TB HDD 
      1GB recovery | 260mb EFI | 1GB OEM | 880GB Windows (C:) | 350MB Recovery | 25GB Lenovo (D:) | 20GB recovery
```

So, to install Arch, what partitions should I resize, and where should I install arch and the bootloader.
Also, does anyone now whats up with the unknown filesystem on the SSD, can I reformat and put arch there?
And why are there so many recovery partitions?

Comment: Little confused about the partitions too. A gig each for "recovery" & "OEM", then 25GB of Lenovo (what's in there?) and another 20GB more "recovery"? If you might actually want to use the recovery stuff later, you may want to check with the manufacturer to see what's what. Making a separate recovery DVD/USB or Windows install DVD/USB might be a good idea, then you could use the drive however you wish. Can `mount` or anything else make any sense of the SSD? Maybe it's just gparted. I've read that sometimes a small SSD is used like a fast disk cache for the slower HDD...

Comment: I've since found that the 16GB SSD is used by ExpressCache, can I disable this and reformat my ssd?

Comment: Disabling the ExpressCache would probably would result in slightly slower Windows performance *sometimes*, maybe during boot? Just a guess, from what I remember reading once somewhere - doing more research on it specifically would be recommended, to find out just how useful it really is. If it were me, I doubt I'd want to trade a small SSD just to save a few seconds at boot time.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't mess with the recovery partitions and so on, unless you know what you are doing. Check with the manufacturer, maybe the manual of the computer?
I would resize the 880 Gb windows partition and put arch on the freed space there. Also, it seems like you have an EFI based system, so you should read up on https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GRUB#UEFI_systems before installing a boot loader.

I suppose that you could use the SSD as disk for your Arch installation, but that would slow down your Windows installation. Also, I would remove ExpressCache from Windows before formatting the SSD if that is what you are going for.
Anyway, many things can go wrong with resizing and such a complex partition layout, so make sure to make a backup before starting ;)

Comment: I have now removed expresscache, amd reformatted the ssd. I made my arch install usb uefi bootable (following your link) and all seems to work fine. Tomorrow I will proceed with the windows resize and actual arch install. Thanks for your help so far.